# Keep Tooltip open as long as mouse is over it

Tags: javafx, tooltip, fxml

I create a `Tooltip` for a `TableColumn` header via `fxml` like this:

```
<TableColumn>
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="someProperty" />
    </cellValueFactory>
    <graphic>
        <Label text="Column 1">
            <tooltip>
                <Tooltip text="Tooltip text" />
            </tooltip>
        </Label>
    </graphic>
</TableColumn>
```

I would like to keep the tooltip open if I move the mouse over the tooltip. Eventually I would like to have clickable links in the tooltip text (Just like Eclipse JavaDoc tooltips).
Is that possible?

**Edit**:
Considering the answer, I am trying the following now:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("test text");
DelayedTooltip beakerTip = new DelayedTooltip();
beakerTip.setDuration(3000);
beakerTip.setText("Science from Base: 12");
beakerTip.isHoveringTarget(label);
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
tooltip.setText("test tooltip text");
label.setTooltip(beakerTip);
myTableColumn.setGraphic(label);
```

Here the problem is that the `label` is not the same as the Tooltip. So if the mouse is over the Tooltip but not over the `label`, the Tooltip is hidden. I cannot pass the Tooltip itself as a hover target, since it is not a `Node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this class now and it works as expected:

```
public class HoveringTooltip extends Tooltip {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private Map<Object, Boolean> mapHoveringTarget2Hovering = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final int duration;

    public HoveringTooltip(int duration) {
        super.setAutoHide(false);
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void addHoveringTarget(Node object) {

        mapHoveringTarget2Hovering.put(object, false);
        object.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            onMouseEntered(object);
        });
        object.setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            onMouseExited(object);
        });
    }

    public void addHoveringTarget(Scene object) {

        mapHoveringTarget2Hovering.put(object, false);
        object.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            onMouseEntered(object);
        });
        object.setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            onMouseExited(object);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

        // super.hide();
    }

    public boolean isHovering() {

        return isHoveringProperty().get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty isHoveringProperty() {

        synchronized(mapHoveringTarget2Hovering) {
            for(Entry<Object, Boolean> e : mapHoveringTarget2Hovering.entrySet()) {
                if(e.getValue()) {
                    // if one hovering target is hovering, return true
                    return new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(true);
                }
            }
            // no hovering on any target, return false
            return new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void onMouseEntered(Object object) {

        // System.err.println("Mouse entered for " + object + ", canelling timer");
        // stop a potentially running hide timer
        timer.cancel();
        mapHoveringTarget2Hovering.put(object, true);
    }

    private synchronized void onMouseExited(Object object) {

        // System.err.println("Mouse exit for " + object + ", starting timer");
        mapHoveringTarget2Hovering.put(object, false);
        startTimer();
    }

    private void startTimer() {

        timer.cancel();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(!isHovering())
                            HoveringTooltip.super.hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, duration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is possible, but it involves basically gutting most of the basic functionality of the tooltip. This is how I implemented the same thing:

First I made a custom tooltip that was based off the basic tooltip(this code is a modification of a similar question)

```
public class DelayedTooltip extends Tooltip {

    private int duration = 0;
    private BooleanProperty isHoveringPrimary = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private BooleanProperty isHoveringSecondary = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public void setDuration(int d) {
        duration = d;
    }

    public BooleanProperty isHoveringPrimaryProperty()
    {
        return isHoveringPrimary;
    }

    public BooleanProperty isHoveringSecondaryProperty()
    {
        return isHoveringSecondary;
    }

    public void isHoveringTargetPrimary(Node node){
        node.setOnMouseEntered(e -> isHoveringPrimary.set(true));
        node.setOnMouseExited(e -> isHoveringPrimary.set(false));
    }

       //Usually you will use the tooltip here so enter tooltip.getGraphic() for the node.
    public void isHoveringTargetSecondary(Node node){
        node.setOnMouseEntered(e -> isHoveringTooltip.set(true)):
        node.setOnMouseExited(e -> isHoveringTooltip.set(false));
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        if(isHoveringPrimary.get()==true || isHoveringTooltip.get()==true)
        {
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(duration));
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);
            timeline.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                    DelayedTooltip.super.hide();
                }
            });
            timeline.play();
        }
        else
        {
            DelayedTooltip.super.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

And then this is how I installed the tooltip

```
    DelayedTooltip beakerTip = new DelayedTooltip();
    beakerTip.setDuration(999999);
    beakerTip.setText("Science from Base: 12");
    beakerTip.isHoveringTargetPrimary(beakerView);
        beakerTip.isHoveringTargetSecondary(beakerTip.geoGraphic());
```

You could edit this and make it into one method with multiple parameters if you so wish, but otherwise, this does work.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, I cannot keep the Tooltip open. I tried setting the TableView as hoovering target and the Tooltip/ the Label itself. Setting the Tooltip itself as a target does not work, since the Tooltip is no Node. beakerTip.getGraphic() returns null..

Comment: @kerner1000 It works fine for me. If you don't want the delay functionality, you can simplify it a bit (if you like), but I don't see the problem.

Comment: @James_D, what do you pass as the hovering target?

Comment: @kerner1000 The node you are setting it to be a tooltip for, of course. So the table column graphic in your case.

Comment: @James_D So that's the Label that is set as graphic for the TableColumn. But the Tooltip is larger than this Label. If the mouse moves away from the Label but stays on top of the Tooltip, the Tooltip disappears, because the mouse is not hovering over the Label anymore.

Comment: @kerner1000 Presumably you can fix the code in the answer so that it accounts for that.

Comment: @kerner1000 For this you can modify the parameters of the DelayedTooltip class to include double parameters, one for the table and one for the tooltip, would do it now but am currently on mobile.

Comment: I have updated the question taking into accout @AdamRen 's answer.

Comment: @kerner1000 I have updated the response to include hovering over the tooltip.

Comment: @kerner1000 Nevermind just tested it and the changes do not work as intended. I'll update it again when I find a proper solution.

Comment: @kerner1000 There you go its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to hack the behavior of a Tooltip:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
 * @author rdeardorff
 */
public class TooltipDelay {

    public static void hackTooltipActivationTimer( Tooltip tooltip, int delay ) {
        hackTooltipTiming( tooltip, delay, "activationTimer" );
    }

    public static void hackTooltipHideTimer( Tooltip tooltip, int delay ) {
        hackTooltipTiming( tooltip, delay, "hideTimer" );
    }

    private static void hackTooltipTiming( Tooltip tooltip, int delay, String property ) {
        try {
            Field fieldBehavior = tooltip.getClass().getDeclaredField( "BEHAVIOR" );
            fieldBehavior.setAccessible( true );
            Object objBehavior = fieldBehavior.get( tooltip );

            Field fieldTimer = objBehavior.getClass().getDeclaredField( property );
            fieldTimer.setAccessible( true );
            Timeline objTimer = (Timeline) fieldTimer.get( objBehavior );

            objTimer.getKeyFrames().clear();
            objTimer.getKeyFrames().add( new KeyFrame( new Duration( delay ) ) );
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```