# Detect mouse hovering over a Tooltip

Tags: javafx, tooltip, mousehover

In relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462622/keep-tooltip-open-as-long-as-mouse-is-over-it) I would like to know if it is possible to trigger an event if the mouse is hovering over a `Tooltip`. I know this method `node.setOnMouseEntered()` but this applies only to instances of `Node` (`Tooltip` does not extend `Node`).

Comment: Oh lol I was just about to edit the other question to fix this.

Comment: Great, you can also answer here if it fits better.

Comment: I do not see the interest to listen to a tooltip if it disappears directly if you leave the control that generates it ?

Comment: @BoHalim see question 41462622 for a usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `scene` from the `Tooltip` and register the event handlers there:

```
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("Something");
Scene tooltipScene = tooltip.getScene();

tooltipScene.setOnMouseEntered(evt -> {
    System.out.println("enter");
});
tooltipScene.setOnMouseExited(evt -> {
    System.out.println("exit");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`tooltip.getGraphic()` will allow you to get a tooltip as a node.

Comment: Not necessarily, this returns null if you dont set the graphic by yourself.

Comment: And I did not read this before submitting changes to the other answer...